# PHP Memcached with Binary Protocol — Junk data returned after `increment()`

Tags: php, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I've started using the [`increment()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.increment.php) method of the PHP Memcached client, and with that switched to the binary protocol. Apparently, `increment()` [is only supported on the binary protocol](https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.increment.php#113004). Occasionally, I'm seeing garbage results come back from incremented keys. For example:

```
$memcached = new \Memcached();
$memcached->setOption(\Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL, TRUE);
```

…

```
$this->cache->increment($key,1,1);
```

…

```
$this->cache->get($key);
```

Output:

```
"1\u0000ants1 0 1\r\n1\r\n1\r\n25\r"
```

Given that the key did not exist before it was incremented at first, and an initial value of `1` was given to the `increment()` call, I'd expect the value returned to be an integer. Instead, the strings returned look like left-over junk, e.g. the `ants` part of that string has no relevance.

Other (possibly) pertinent info:

- I'm seeing this on a range of different keys
- Our Memcached server is an AWS Elasticache instance
- Other clients using the same cache node are not using the binary protocol.
- All clients are running the same OS (CentOS), PHP and Memcached versions.

Comment: Would you happen to be using EC2s of both 32-bit and 64-bit builds both writing to this memcached instance? Also which version of memcached PHP bindings are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## tl;dr;

*This is a bug in the PHP extension code...*

---

I dug into the PHP extension code that wraps libmemcached and the libmemcached API code itself, but I think I've found the possible underlying cause of your problem...

If you take a look at the PHP `Memcached::increment()` implementation you'll see on [line 1858 of `php_memcached.c`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PECL/memcached/php_memcached.c#1858)

```
status = memcached_increment_with_initial(m_obj->memc, key, key_len, (unsigned int)offset, initial, expiry, &value);
```

The problem here is that `offset` may or may not be 64 bits wide. The [libmemcached API](http://docs.libmemcached.org/memcached_auto.html) tells us that the `memcached_increment_with_initial` function signature expects a `uint64_t` for `offset` whereas here `offset` is declared `long` and then cast to `unsigned int`.

So if we were do something like this...

```
$memcached = new memcached;
$memcached->addServer('127.0.0.1','11211');
$memcached->setOption(\Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL, TRUE);

$memcached->delete('foo'); // remove the key if it already exists
$memcached->increment('foo',1,1);

var_dump($memcached->get('foo'));
```

You'd see something like...

```
string(22) "8589934592
"
```

as the output from that script. **Note this only works if the key `foo` does not already exist on that memcached server.** Also note the length of that string at `22` characters, when clearly it's not supposed to be anywhere near that.

If you look at the hex representation of that string....

```
 var_dump(bin2hex($memcached->get('foo')));
```

The result is clear garbage at the end...

```
 string(44) "38353839393334353932000d0a000000000000000000"
```

The object that was being stored was clearly corrupted between the casts. So you may end up getting the same result as me or you may end up getting completely broken data as you have demonstrated above. It depends on how the cast effected the chunk of memory being stored at the time (which is falling into undefined behavior here). Also the only seemingly root cause for this is using an initial value with increment (using `increment` subsequently after this does not demonstrate that problem or if the key already exists).

I guess the problem of this stems from the fact that the libmemcached API has two different size requirements for `offset` parameter between `memcached_increment` and `memcached_increment_with_initial`

```
memcached_increment(memcached_st *ptr, const char *key, size_t key_length, uint32_t offset, uint64_t *value)
```

The former takes `uint32_t` whereas the later takes `uint64_t` and PHP's extension code casts both to `unsigned int`, which would be equivalent to `uint32_t` pretty much.

This discrepency in the width of the `offset` parameter is likely what causes the key to be corrupted somehow between the calling PHP extension code and the API code.